# ambiguity of [CCS] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

There are two completely different microcontroller IDEs, both of whose names commonly abbreviate to, "CCS"

- Custom Computer Software (CCS) compiler and IDE for Microchip PIC microcontrollers.
- Code Composer Studio (CCS) made by TI for MSP430s, Stellaris, OMAP, etc

This may be causing confusion, especially for those who are new to the microcontroller field and are choosing a microcontroller family for the first time.

I propose that we keep [ccs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ccs) associated with Custom Computer Software, and make a new [ccstudio](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ccstudio) or [ti-ccstudio](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ti-ccstudio) or [ti-ccs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ti-ccs) for TI Code Composer Studio.

### Outcome

New tags [ti-ccstudio](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ti-ccstudio) and [pic-ccs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pic-ccs) created (with wiki excerpts).  Existing threads manually retagged (there were only 10 of them).

Comment: I vote for **ccstudio**, because TI uses this abbreviation too.

Comment: maybe make `ccs` the synonym for something less ambiguous?

Comment: Constant Current Source?

Comment: @W5VO  That too, although nobody have used [ccs] for Constant Current Source.  Not yet.

Comment: Good work. Now we finally have a tag free for *Computer Controlled Simulation* or *Constant Current Source*.

Answer (score 3):

If you keep the [ccs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ccs) tag CCStudio users will also use that tag, wanna bet? :-) As a matter of fact they'll use *both* tags. I would go for [pic-ccs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pic-ccs) and [ti-ccstudio](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ti-ccstudio), both contain "ccs", so will show when the acronym is typed in.

And incinerate[ccs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ccs). I mean actually destroy it; if it keeps popping up when users start typing "ccs" they'll use it. You could make it a synonym for one of the two, but then the [pic-css](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pic-css) may be assigned where [ti-ccstudio](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ti-ccstudio) was meant

Comment: I think we just need to make sure we have both tags with nice wikis and see if that solves the issue. But if it keeps reappearing we can destroy it. There are only 9 uses right now, I dont see an issue. I do think the preposition on both might be confusing for finding the tag.

Comment: Why not keep 'ccs' as a "disambiguation" entry, much like the same concept on Wikipedia? Its excerpt would provide a pointer to the two other tags. This isn't the last time that this sort of thing is going to happen.

Comment: @DaveTweed  Leaving CCS as a disambiguation entry is not a bad idea.  Except, I doubt that the disambiguation will be actually read.  I'd vote for incinerating the simple 'ccs'.